# Movie about a family who gets a game from a friend and are transported to an old well as a challenge

Tags: story-identification, movie

Please help me! I can't remember the name of this movie, but it's basically about a family who gets a game from some friend of theirs. It's an old board game, made from stone, and there are two sticks used as dice.

So, the family decides to play it, and each time someone throws the sticks at the middle of the game board, it shows what to do. One of the tasks is to answer 3 questions. If you lie, the entire family has to go through a challenge.

They get teleported to an old well and they have to get out of there by pressing colorful bricks. **It's not *Jumanji* or *Zahura*!**

Comment: Oof... my first bets are certainly those two. Stick dice were fairly common in some cultures and is a distinctive detail. Do you know when you watched it and where? Was it in English?

Comment: tv It was in english

Answer (score 13):

The movie you're looking for is a German movie called **Manatu - Nur die Wahrheit rettet dich** ("Manatu - Only the truth saves you"). You can find it on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0904099/).

It matches your description perfectly. They get the game from a friend, the game is made of stone, they throw two sticks as dices, they have to answer questions and get teleported to a well like structure when they lie.

Comment: Welcome! That is an excellent answer for a first post.