# A film about children playing a board game where they get sucked into the game?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched a film as a child probably 15 years ago about two children who play a board game and get taken into the game and every square they land on they find themselves in a situation for the game. It is not Zathura or Jumanjii. The kids were quite young about 8/9??

Comment: You just disqualified the only two I could think of.  Do you know anything else about the movie?  Is it a spacey Gane,  a jungley game? Try to throw out some more details if you can remember them.

Comment: Possible duplicate?  [movie-about-a-family-who-gets-a-game-from-a-friend-and-are-transported-to-an-old](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93933/movie-about-a-family-who-gets-a-game-from-a-friend-and-are-transported-to-an-old)  The only answer given was never accepted by that person, but let us know if it rings a bell for you.

Comment: Also this one with no answers, but perhaps the details in the question sound familiar?  [identify-a-story-in-which-jumanji-zathura-type-board-game-gave-a-player-a-hot-mermaid-wife](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154047/identify-a-story-in-which-jumanji-zathura-type-board-game-gave-a-player-a-hot-me)

Comment: Was this definitely a film, and not, say, a game show?

Comment: I wonder if this might be a VHS or DVD of "Wonders in Letterland", the first of the T-Bag series to have aired on UK television in the 80s (see information at http://hight.50webs.com/series/wonders/ep1.html). There were indeed two young children travelling through the squares of the boardgame - Debbie (the protagonist) and Thomas/T-Shirt (in every series he would be brainwashed into serving as the antagonist's sidekick - but usually by the final episode he would regain control and actively help the good guys.) If you think it might be I can submit an answer instead of this comment.

Comment: There was a Simpson horror episode based on this. Unless it was based on Jumanji.

Answer (score 5):

Was this the episode "The Haunted House Game" from the Goosebumps TV Series?

https://goosebumps.fandom.com/wiki/The_Haunted_House_Game/TV_episode

Here's a relevant excerpt from the plot:

. . . Nadine and Jonathan kindly agree to go inside the old house to find the little girl's cat for her. Inside, the two find the haunted house game and decide to play it, only to get magically sucked into it. Forced to play the game if they wish to escape alive (at least according to the written instructions they are given), Nadine and Jonathan meet Noah and Annie, two other children who tell them they have been sucked into the game as well.

The image below might ring a bell if this is indeed what you're looking for:

[image: Rules for Playing the Haunted House Game]

Being the Goosebumps TV show, the age of the characters seem to range from ~7 years old to adolescent age. The main characters are adolescents, but there are side characters that are also stuck in / or part of the game of younger age.